# Why does this code not navigate to the subpage?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I am migrating an app from react-router-dom v5 to v6. The v5 app works by clicking buttons to navigate to a sub page. It changed the page by doing a history.push. Now I am trying the v6 way but it does not work as expected. I even see the desired url in the address bar but the page does not render. I have read that the navigate hook should be called in an event handler which I have in the demo code.

What am I missing?

How should I debug this?

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Navigate, Route, Routes, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function ListOfThings() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleClickCreate( e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    navigate( 'CreateNewThing' );
  }

  function handleClickShow( e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    navigate( 'ShowThing' );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>ListOfThings</h2>
      <button onClick={handleClickCreate}>Go To Create New Thing Page</button>
      <button onClick={handleClickShow}>Go To Show Thing Page</button>
    </>
  );
}

function CreateNewThing() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleClick() {
    navigate( '/ListOfThings' );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Create New Thing Page</h2>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go To List Of Things</button>
    </>
  );
}

function ShowThing() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleClick() {
    navigate( '/ListOfThings' );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Show Thing Page</h2>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go To List Of Things</button>
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/ListOfThings' element={<ListOfThings />} >
          <Route path='CreateNewThing' element={<CreateNewThing />} />
          <Route path=':id' element={<ShowThing />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/' element={ <Navigate to='ListOfThings' replace /> } />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SubPage` component is rendered by a nested route, the parent layout route component necessarily should render an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their `element` content into.

```
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function Home() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleClick() {
    navigate('Subpage');
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go To Sub Page</button>
      <div>
        <Outlet /> // <-- nested route content rendered here
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/Home' element={<Home />}>
          <Route path='Subpage' element={<SubPage />} /> // <-- rendered into Outlet
        </Route>
        <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to='Home' replace />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

For more information see:

- [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes)
- [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets)

If you prefer that the `Home` and `SubPage` components be rendered individually then move the `Home` component *off* the layout route and render it as an index route.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/Home'>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />             // "/home"
          <Route path='Subpage' element={<SubPage />} /> // "/home/subpage"
        </Route>
        <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to='Home' replace />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

- [Index Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#index-routes)
- [Pathless Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#pathless-routes)

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. The Outlet solution is not what I am looking for. Maybe I used the wrong wording? I know I can render the Subpage via the Outlet but that makes it part of the Home page. I want Home and Subpage to render separately and appear as independent pages. I have updated the demo code if it makes my intent clearer.

Comment: @StephenL No problem, check my updated answer. Gist is to render `Home` on an index route instead of the layout route.